# Exclude columns from Minus operations in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to know if you can exclude a column from a `MINUS` operation

For example:

```
select column 1, column 2, column 3
from table 1

minus

select column 1, column 2
from table 2;
```

while column 3 is excluded from the operation.

Is there anyway to do that?

Thank you

Comment: for minus the number of columns must be the same (and be compatible data types) the rules are the same as a union

Comment: No, the number of columns must be same and compatible in both queries. What would it mean to apply `minus` on result sets with different structures? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: yes, what are you trying to do? could you present a sample, there is probably a way just not with minus

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few alternatives.

**#1**

Minus without column3 then rejoin result to the original table to get the missing values for column3.

```
select *
from (
        select column1, column2
        from table1
        minus
        select column1, column2
        from table2
    )
join table1 using (column1, column2)
```

**#2**

Use an ANTI-JOIN the NOT EXISTS clause should work the same as NOT IN anyway.

```
select column1, column2, column3
from table1
where (column1, column2) not in (
        select column1, column2
        from table2
)
```

Comment: i had to join with the table to get the missing column. Thank you :)

Comment: What would happen if both are same tables ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are after this?

```
select table1.column1, table1.column2, table1.column3
from table1
left table2 on table1.column1 = table2.column1 and table1.column2 = table2.column2
where table1.id IS NULL
```

This will result in only those table1 records that do not have matching column1 and column2 values in table2.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this:

```
with t(a, b, c) as (
  select 1, 2, 3 from dual union all
  select 2, 2, null from dual union all
  select 2, 3, 5 from dual
), t1(a, b) as (
  select 1, 2 from dual union all
  select 2, 2 from dual union all
  select 2, 3 from dual
), t2 as (
  select a, b, c from t
  minus
  select a, b, null from t1
)
select a, b from t2

A   B
-----
1   2
2   3
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/33873)

If you have null values in your column3 and you want to escape them you can escape them like this:

```
with t(a, b, c) as (
  select 1, 2, 3 from dual union all
  select 2, 2, null from dual union all
  select 2, 3, 5 from dual
), t1(a, b) as (
  select 1, 2 from dual union all
  select 2, 2 from dual union all
  select 2, 3 from dual
), t3 as (
  select a, b, nvl(c, -1) from t
  minus
  select a, b, null from t1
)
select a, b from t3

A   B
-----
1   2
2   2
2   3
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/33874)

Comment: What does it mean "differ to null"? Do you mean if column3 is null?

Comment: ((a, b, c)) minus ((a, b, null)) will always return ((a, b, c)) when c!=null

Comment: @AlessandroRossi especially for you I updated my answer with two examples of output, mainly there was changed nothing, where do you see a problem?

Comment: In that sample the excepted result is to have no rows because except for column c the 2 table have the same value. You query returned all the 3 rows. It is wrong. Hope to be clear!

Comment: @AlessandroRossi Clear enough, I guess I didn't understand what the author of the question.